# Python requests-html session GET correct usage

Tags: python, ubuntu, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm working on a web scraper that needs to open several thousand pages and get some data.
Since one of the data fields I need the most is only loaded after all javascripts of the site have been loaded, I'm using html-requests to render the page and then get the data I need.

I want to know, what's the best way to do this?

1- Open a session at the start of the script, do my whole scraping and then close the session when the script finishes after thousands of "clicks" and several hours?

2- Or should I open a session everytime I open a link, render the page, get the data, and then close the session, and repeat n times in a cycle?

Currently I'm doing the 2nd option, but I'm getting a problem. This is the code I'm using:

```
def getSellerName(listingItems):
    for item in listingItems:
        builtURL = item['href']
        try:
            session = HTMLSession()
            r = session.get(builtURL,timeout=5)
            r.html.render()
            sleep(1)
            sellerInfo = r.html.search("<ul class=\"seller_name\"></ul></div><a href=\"{user}\" target=")["user"]
            ##
            ##Do some stuff with sellerinfo
            ##
            session.close()
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
            log.exception("TimeOut Ex: ")
            continue
        except:
            log.exception("Gen Ex")
            continue
        finally:    
            session.close()
        break
```

This works pretty well and is quite fast. However, after about 1.5 or 2 hours, I start getting OS exception like this one:

**OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files**

And then that's it, I just get this exception over and over again, until I kill the script.

I'm guessing I need to close something else after every get and render, but I'm not sure what or if I'm doing it correctly.

Any help and/or suggestions, please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should create a session object outside the loop

```
def getSellerName(listingItems):
    session = HTMLSession()
    for item in listingItems:
    //code
```